# Multiple Spring Components\ Beans of the same type

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a base class `Foo` and multiple classes that inherit from it.

Until now I've needed exactly one of each

So I just did:

```
@Autowired 
private List<Foo> foos;
```

But things has changed and I'd like to generate multiple objects of every type (i.e. `x` instances for `Foo1`, `y` instances for `Foo2` etc)

How can I do that using Spring Boot?

Note: I don't really need it to be populated into the list.

**EDIT:**

I'll explain further about the problem I'm facing. Each class represents a type of task (It's a `Runnable`). Each task has a fixed number of threads. I'd like to instantiate a new object for every thread.

So my question is: How to utilise Spring for that cause? Back when I needed only one instance for every task it was easy (see the `List<Foo>` example)

Comment: What is the point of this? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: For a starter, I want to enjoy Spring's component scan feature.

Comment: Each instance of `Foo` is "attached" to a thread

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Why not? I want Spring to instantiate those objects. I just need multiple of them, for every type.

Comment: What is your use case, can you explain what exactly you want to do with those multiple instances? This sounds like something no one would ever use to me.

Comment: @Lino, As I explained, each class is a type of task. There are multiple threads (fixed number) for every task. I want to "assign" a new instance (it's a Runnable) for every thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR;

I propose a solution which includes a bit of work, but is more clean in most cases.

It uses a factory which holds all the dependencies of `Foo` and we make `Foo` not a spring bean anymore. So we don't rely on Spring to instantiate `n` instances of `Foo`, instead we can programatically decide how many we want to create.

This of course has some pros and cons:

#### Pro:

- Possible to programatically create `n` instances. (can be set via property, can be computed, may be injected...)
- We don't use spring to decide how many instances are created
- (there are possible more, but I can't think of more at the moment)

#### Con:

- You have an overhead of creating a new class (factory) for every type you'd like to create

---

### Actual answer

#### 1. Create an interface

This will be used to create your `n` instances of a type:

```
interface Factory<T> {
    T create();
}
```

#### 2. Create implementations

This must be done for every type you'd like to construct. Additionally every created implementation must be declared as a spring bean:

```
// Our object we want to create
class Foo {
    private final Dependency1 d1;
    private final Dependency2 d2;

    public Foo(Dependency1 d1, Dependency2 d2){
        this.d1 = d1;
        this.d2 = d2;
    }

    // methods of foo
}

// our factory for the object
@Component
class FooFactory implements Factory<Foo>{
    private final Dependency1 d1;
    private final Dependency2 d2;

    @Autowired
    public FooFactory(Dependency1 d1, Dependency2 d2){
        this.d1 = d1;
        this.d2 = d2;
    }

    @Override
    public Foo create(){
        return new Foo(d1, d2);
    }
}
```

#### 3. Inject the factory

This is done in the service we want to create `n` instances of `Foo`:

```
@Service
class MyService{
    private final FooFactory fooFactory;

    @Autowired
    public MyService(FooFactory fooFactory){
        this.fooFactory = fooFactory;
    }

    public void doSomething(){
        // can of course be generated with a normal for loop too
        List<Foo> foos = IntStream.range(0, 10)
            .mapToObj(i -> fooFactory.create())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // do something with 10 foo instances   
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lino! but yeah, I agree that it makes your code bloated with classes

Comment: @yaseco Well spring already makes you create more classes than you'd really wish for, so it may not be a really big disadvantage ;)

Comment: @yaseco actually, after some more researching spring already has something similar implemented: [ObjectFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ObjectFactoryCreatingFactoryBean.html)

Answer (score 3):

If im understanding correctly your question, you need more than one instance of a bean then you need to declare scope of that bean to PROTOTYPE because by default spring is making them SINGLETON (one bean per container). To make your bean PROTOTYPE you just need to add this annotation `@Scope("prototype")` to your class.
Here is some in depth reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html

HTH

Comment: That's sounds interesting. And how would you generate each bean?

Comment: Assuming you injecting those beans into singleton this link might be useful for further clarification: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-prototype-bean-into-singleton